# Changing text logo to image logo in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to change the text logo to a image logo. I spotted the code in header.php. But i am not sure how to change it. I am using Point Theme. Here is the code:

```
<?php if ($mts_options['mts_logo'] != '') { ?>
                <?php if( is_front_page() || is_home() || is_404() ) { ?>
                        <h1 id="logo" class="image-logo">
                            <?php list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($mts_options['mts_logo']); ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $mts_options['mts_logo']; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" <?php echo $attr; ?>></a>
                        </h1><!-- END #logo -->
                <?php } else { ?>
                      <h2 id="logo" class="image-logo">
                            <?php list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($mts_options['mts_logo']); ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $mts_options['mts_logo']; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" <?php echo $attr; ?>></a>
                        </h2><!-- END #logo -->
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <?php if( is_front_page() || is_home() || is_404() ) { ?>
                        <h1 id="logo" class="text-logo">
                            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
                        </h1><!-- END #logo -->
                <?php } else { ?>
                      <h2 id="logo" class="text-logo">
                            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
                        </h2><!-- END #logo -->
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: It looks like your theme supports a image logo. Find out where `$mts_options['mts_logo']` comes from and how to set it.

Comment: $mts_options['mts_logo'] comes from <?php $mts_options = get_option('point'); ?>. But i can't find get_option() function.

Comment: `get_option` is a WordPress function. Look for `set_option` using `'mts_logo'`.

Comment: I changed above code to `<h1 id="logo" class="image-logo">
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="http://LOGOURL.COM/GOESHERE.png" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"></a>
</h1><!-- END #logo -->` . Now it works fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed above code to

`<h1 id="logo" class="image-logo"> <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="http://LOGOURL.COM/GOESHERE.png" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"></a> </h1><!-- END #logo -->` .

Now it works fine